# linq to sql Distinct and orderby

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
var result = table1.Join(table2, o => o.ProgramID, t => t.ProgramID, (o, t) => new { o.ProgramID, t.Program })
         .OrderBy(t => t.Program)
         .Distinct();
```

the above linq statement actually returns the correct result, but he sql generated (below) is not as simple as it could be

```
SELECT [t2].[ProgramID], [t2].[Program]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[ProgramID], [t1].[Program]
    FROM [table1] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [table2] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ProgramID] = [t1].[ProgramID]
    ) AS [t2]
ORDER BY [t2].[Program]
```

I would have thought the sql below is far cleaner but I'm not sure of the linq statement to achieve it.

```
select distinct 
    o.ProgramID, 
    t.Program 
from 
    table1 0 
    inner join table2 t on t.ProgramID = o.ProgramID 
order by t.Program
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried messing with the order of method invocations? I.e. swap orderby and distinct?

Comment: Awesome, swapped them and worked a treat.

Comment: new sql looks like
SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[ProgramID], [t1].[Program]
FROM [tbl_Batch] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [tbl_Program] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ProgramID] = [t1].[ProgramID]

Comment: hmm... answered too soon, swapping them around drops the orderby :(

Answer (score 36):

I don't know if it will help, but you can try something like this;

```
var result = (from o in table1
              join t in table2 on o.ProgramID equals t.ProgramID
              orderby t.Program
              select new { o.ProgramID, t.Program }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Yeah that was what I was trying, but unfortunately the Distinct() totally wipes out the orderby.
but as Reese suggested if you do this:
var result = (from o in table1 
              join t in table2 on o.ProgramID equals t.ProgramID 
              select new { o.ProgramID, t.Program }).OrderBy(t => t.Program).Distinct();
it works

Comment: And what do you have to do, when you want to Order more than one attributes? Something like this: OrderBy(t => new {t.Program, t.ProgramName, t.Description}).Distinct(); ?

Answer (score 12):

I tried this and that works:

```
var result = (from o in table1
              join t in table2 on o.ProgramID equals t.ProgramID
              select new { o.ProgramID, t.Program })
              .Distinct().OrderBy(t => t.Program)
                         .ThenBy(t => t.ProgramName)
                         .ThenBy(t => t.Description);
```

First you do Distinct and then OrderBy, then OrderBy works.

Comment: Thank you, big help.

Answer (score 5):

Profile the two queries, comparing stats-IO and the actual execution plan. It is entirely possible that it makes zero difference to the SQL server.

If you really want known TSQL, use ExecuteQuery-of-T and pass in the TSQL yourself. Maybe include some lock hints too (most commonly: NOLOCK)