# How can I get distinct results from this LINQ query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Below is my ERD and sample data. Note, I'm using Entity Framework and Code first to control my database.

[image]

For the project named **Vacation**, return all the **DISTINCT** users who have a "true" value in **UserBooleanAttributes** table for either the **Parents** or **Teens** rows defined in the **UserAttributes** table.

Here is my current attempt:

```
                var myQuery =
                    from P in context.Projects
                    join UA in context.UserAttributes on P.ProjectID equals UA.ProjectID
                    join UBA in context.UserBooleanAttributes on UA.UserAttributeID equals UBA.UserAttributeID
                    join U in context.Users on UBA.UserID equals U.UserID
                    where P.ProjectID == 1
                    where UBA.Value == true
                    where (UA.UserAttributeID == 1 || UA.UserAttributeID == 2)
                    select new { uba = U };
```

This returns 6 users, with **e@acme.org** being listed twice.  Is there a LINQ way of returning distinct values?  I suppose I could convert this to a list then filter, but I'd rather have the Database do the work.

I'd rather avoid using lambda expressions if possible.  Once again, I want the database to do the work, and not have to write code to union/intersect result groups.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid lambda expressions? Also, this is 2 questions. Please stick to one question per... question!

Comment: Oh, and to answer your first problem.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318909/linq-to-sql-distinct-and-orderby

Comment: I want to avoid lambda expressions because I find the language less natural for devs used to SQL.

Comment: Lambda is part of C#, the devs should get used to it.

Comment: Changing it to var myQuery = (from P ...  select new { uba = U }).Distinct(); did the trick.  Just for kicks, can you add a solution of doing the same query in lambda format?  (Yes, they should get used to it)