# How To Convert Linq To Sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want write code for table, I know in SQL Server, but I don't know Linq or EF.

SQL Server code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Driver
WHERE id IN (SELECT Driver
             FROM Drive_Car
             WHERE Drive_Car.Finish_Date IS NOT NULL)
```

I wrote this code in EF but it does not match the SQL Server results:

```
var drivers = db.Drivers
                .Where(d => db.Drive_Car
                              .Where(dc => dc.Driver == d.ID && dc.Finish_Date != null)
                              .Select(dc => dc.Driver)
                              .Contains(d.ID));
```

Comment: If you want to convert **Sql to Linq**, then why does your title say *exactly the opposite*?

Comment: No this form, any way i want get code linq like sql server

Comment: `it does not match the SQL Server result` in which way? What is the generated SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
var drivers = db.Drivers
                .Where(d => db.Drive_Car
                              .Any(dc => dc.Driver == d.ID && dc.Finish_Date != null));
```

This leads to `Exists`, which is in the end about the same as the `IN` approach. Duplicating rows through join and uniquifing them back through `distinct` is not always optimized away and you may end up with more overhead than necessary, so I would not prefer that way.

Comment: I agree with that join with distinct it is not best practice. Also i provided another method by splitting the command into 2 parts. But i think the syntax you provided is better +1

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same result using a Join operation. Or to split the command into 2 parts.

*Linq SQL-Like syntax:*

```
var query =
   (from d in db.Driver
   join dc in dc.Drive_Car on dc.Driver equals d.ID
   where dc.Finish_Date != null
   select d).Distinct();
```

*Other method (Split into 2 parts)*

```
var lst =
   (from dc in dc.Drive_Car 
   where dc.Finish_Date != null
   select dc.Driver).Distinct().ToList();

var query =
   (from d in db.Driver
    where lst.Contains(d.ID)
   select d);
```

**References:**

- [Join/Where with LINQ and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda)
- [linq to sql Distinct and orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318909/linq-to-sql-distinct-and-orderby)